# UiPath selector not work in Google Chrome alert message box when extracting data

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I have to try the extract data from Google Chrome alert message text.
But when I use Get Text activity and click on Indicate On Screen alert box not highlighted.

[image]

Whole browser windows selected highlighted instead of.

[image]

I have stuck to extract Reports - Upload Yearly Report confirmation id from alert box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to solve this is image recognition. So you **search** for the OK **button as image**. You can do that with the [**Click Image**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/click-image) activity.

But in case you are using the process with another language you might have some issues.

**Update:**
You said you need the text. So you could try the UiPath Connect [**Browser Get PopUp Text**](https://connect.uipath.com/marketplace/components/browser-get-popup-text). Note that this only works on Chrome.

Comment: I have already done this for OK button using Image Click Activity, but my requirement is getting a text from alert box.

Comment: Ok you didn't say that. And already tried with ORC activities? They should work. Also added another alternative.